# how to use "vscode" module in child_process

Tags: vscode-extensions

I started a child_process in my extension process:

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const childProcess = fork(scriptPath);
```

In my child_process script, I required the `vscode` module:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

const document = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document;
```

Then I encountered this error:

```
Cannot find module 'vscode'
```

I understand that `vscode` might be a special module. In the  `webpack.config.js` file, the `vscode` module is marked as externals:

```
externals: ['vscode']
```

Is there any way to use the `vscode` module in my extension child_process?

try to use "vscode" module in my extension child_process